# Assign cell to variable and variable to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am a complete beginner at VBA so sorry for this simple question:

I want to assign cell A1 to a variable '`num`', then I want to multiply the '`num`' with 4 and assign the new value to '`num2`' then  print the result to cell A2.

If you can help me with this I can proceed by myself :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim num As Long, num2 As Long
    num = [A1] * 4
    num2 = num
    [A2] = num2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Even thought this doesn't reply directly (assigning a variable to a cell depend on what you want to assign: the cell itself? its address? the value?) Another possibility (if you need your A2 to always change if A1 changes) which basically insert a formula in your A2 cell:

```
Sub demo()
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Formula = "=4*" & ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Note that `ActiveSheet` here can be whichever sheet you want to use (you may select a different sheet with `Worksheets("WorksheetName")` or with `Worksheets(WorksheetPosition)`.
Of course this would work only if you need only to multiply for 4 your cell

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was bad form to use unnecessary variables.

How about:

```
Sub demo()
[A2] = [A1] * 4
end sub
```

Comment: Well exactly, thought the same thing

Comment: Except the other variable isn't unnecessary, it is used later - but that is unnecessary information in relation to this question so I left it out.
In this example I left that in so someone could tell me how to asign one variable to another because I didn't know. Thats why it is necessary